# Replace Null value in a json field with groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to replace the null value for a particular nested json array field campaign with a json array, My input json is below

```
{"id":1,"campaign":{"id":10,"cost":0,"name":"Test"},"type":1,"typeName":"Email"},
{"id":2,"campaign":null,"type":2,"typeName":"File"},
{"id":3,"campaign":{"id":20,"cost":0,"name":"Test2"},"type":20,"typeName":"Visit"}
```

My Output should be as below

```
{"id":1,"campaign":{"id":10,"cost":0,"name":"Test"},"type":1,"typeName":"Email"},
{"id":2,"campaign":{"id":null,"cost":null,"name":null},"type":2,"typeName":"File"},
{"id":3,"campaign":{"id":20,"cost":0,"name":"Test2"},"type":20,"typeName":"Visit"}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the simplest regex:

```
String input = '[{"id":1,"campaign":{"id":10,"cost":0,"name":"Test"},"type":1,"typeName":"Email"}, {"id":2,"campaign":null,"type":2,"typeName":"File"}, {"id":3,"campaign":{"id":20,"cost":0,"name":"Test2"},"type":20,"typeName":"Visit"}]'

String output = input.replaceAll( '"campaign":null', '"campaign":{"id":null,"cost":null,"name":null}' )

groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint output
```

returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "campaign": {
            "id": 10,
            "cost": 0,
            "name": "Test"
        },
        "type": 1,
        "typeName": "Email"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "campaign": {
            "id": null,
            "cost": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "type": 2,
        "typeName": "File"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "campaign": {
            "id": 20,
            "cost": 0,
            "name": "Test2"
        },
        "type": 20,
        "typeName": "Visit"
    }
]
```

Comment: Nice one:-) It will not get simpler indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your json is a list of maps and if the key is `campaign` and value is `null` you want to replace the value with `[id:null, cost:null, name:null]`.
Assuming the values of the nested maps are only other maps or literals, it is probably easiest to traverse it recursively.

```groovy
Map traverse(Map map, String searchKey, searchVal, replVal) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v ->
        if(v instanceof Map){
            [k, traverse(v, searchKey, searchVal, replVal)]
        } else {
            (k == searchKey && v == searchVal) ? [k, replVal] : [k, v]
        }
    }
}

def input = new JsonSlurper().parseText('''[{"id":1,"campaign":{"id":10,"cost":0,"name":"Test"},"type":1,"typeName":"Email"}, {"id":2,"campaign":null,"type":2,"typeName":"File"}, {"id":3,"campaign":{"id":20,"cost":0,"name":"Test2"},"type":20,"typeName":"Visit"}]''')
def desiredOutput = new JsonSlurper().parseText('''[{"id":1,"campaign":{"id":10,"cost":0,"name":"Test"},"type":1,"typeName":"Email"}, {"id":2,"campaign":{"id":null,"cost":null,"name":null},"type":2,"typeName":"File"}, {"id":3,"campaign":{"id":20,"cost":0,"name":"Test2"},"type":20,"typeName":"Visit"}]''')

def result = input.collect {traverse(it, "campaign", null, [id:null, cost:null, name:null])}
assert result == desiredOutput
String modifiedJson = JsonOutput.toJson(result)

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(modifiedJson)
```